В VScode cбились стили
При загрузке VScode (точнее cursor, но у VScode такая же фигня) на долю секунды появляется нормальные стили, как и должны быть и были раньше:

Но потом имена переменные становятся белыми (это появилось после какой-то ошибки загрузки):

Но в описании они нормального цвета:

В нете ничего не нашёл, подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Перебирать расширения.

Я долго бродил по интернету, ничего не находил. Брал разные ответы, тыкался и тут! Я чисто из любопытства изменил один параметр:
Я был на этом ответе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61829218/vscode-how-do-i-change-the-color-of-constants-only-in-a-javascript-file
Посмотрел последний ответ, стал тыкаться и поставил
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "enabled": false, // enable semantic highlighting for all themes
}

Я не знаю, что это значит, но теперь редактор нормальный:

